# ICollection cast problem

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Is there any solution to solve the problem with this cast example? I need to add a new element to the collection, so I have to solve it.

```
    IEnumerable enumerable;
    IEnumerable enumerable2;
    enumerable = new ObservableCollection<Something>();
    enumerable2 = new ObservableCollection<Object>();


    ICollection<Object> try = (ICollection<Object>)enumerable;      //Don’t work
    ICollection<Object> try2 = (ICollection<Object>)enumerable2;    //Work
```

Comment: If you use a different generic type, then they are different types. You cannot cast T<X> to T<V>, even if V extends/implements X

Comment: ok. So there isn't any solution.:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure 100% that this is what you mean, but have you tried this:

```
IEnumerable<Object> try3 = enumerable.Cast<Object>();
```

Ok, it didn't work, how about dynamic typing:

```
dynamic var = new Something();
dynamic try1 = enumerable;      
try1.Add(var);
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. And with this method I guess I get a new Collection, so I can't add a new element to the original (enumerable) collection.

Answer (score 2):

Check out covariance and contravariance with generic parameters in C# 4.  It might provide you with more information for future when faced with such problems.

Answer (score 0):

If all you know is `object`, then the non-generic interfaces are your friend:

```
IList list = (IList)foo;
list.Add(yourItem);
```

However! Not all enumerable items are lists, so not all can be added in this way. `IList` underpins a lot of data-binding, so is a good bet.

Answer (score 0):

"try" is a reserved word in C#. Have you tried another variable name? or you could use @try if you need to use the "try" variable name.

Comment: Sorry it's just a quick sample.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the something collection and insert the elements into the object one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Cast extension combined with a ToList.

```
IEnumerable ie1 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
ICollection<object> ic1 = (ICollection<object>)ie1.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Or iterate through manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the relevant code, it is perhaps time to rethink the design a little. One often tries to use the most restricted interface possible that can still achieve the desired result. It seems in this case that *IEnumerable* cannot achieve that result, if one of the things you want to do is to add new items. Changing to a more appropriate type might be a better solution than having to cast the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic typing works (Only one bad thing, that I have to link windows.csharp and system.core dlls, which are ~1MB, so it's not the best for a silverlight app, but It's the best solution, which I know now.)